# Defined combinations of objects design pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

My head is hurting trying to figure out which would be the best design pattern after researching some on the internet. The problem I am trying to solve, is the creation of combination of objects.

For example, I have object combinations where an Event object will need to be created with a defined number of Task objects:

Event 1 - Task 1, Task 2, Task 3

Event 2 - Task 2, Task 3

Ideally, I want a simple way of creating Event objects, without something like:

```
Event.Add(Task1)
Event.Add(Task2)
```

etc etc
Ideally I want to see something like Event1.Add(Task1).Add(Task2).Add(Task3).

I also need to be able to retrieve the Tasks from Events as separate objects on their own.

And the Tasks need to be re-usable.

Comment: Search over collection initializers for C#, or use AddRange with arrays of objects

Comment: You don't always need a pattern to solve a problem.

Comment: Well, the example I've provided is to simplify the problem, and something decent needed to be put in place for a growing 20+ events 50+ tasks to accommodate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a little fluent foo like so...

`var e = new EventFoo().Add(new Task()).Add(new Task())`;

```
public class EventFoo
{
    public EventFoo()
    {
        Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; private set; }

    public EventFoo Add(Task task)
    {
        Tasks.Add(task);
        return this;
    }
}
```

If you have a regular set of events to create, you can also move their creation to a factory.

Comment: This was one of my options too. I think this will do for now, don't know if this will still be sustainable in a growing number of events and tasks, the maintainability of it.

Comment: That's where a factory or builder pattern could come in handy, but no need to build those until they are needed.

Comment: With the builder pattern, don't I still have to define all the types of Event objects as in terms of event handlers or separate classes? The only thing that is different from event to event is the number of tasks. So I'd really just want to stick with 2 classes Event and Task, if that's possible :) There must be a better way to manage the high number of those objects that only may be vary in a value of one of their attributes

Comment: No, the builder pattern just gives you a way to create versions of objects that are configured differently for whatever reason -- don't have to be different types.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. I've also looked at other patterns like chain of responsibility, what would you think about that one for this case?

Comment: CoR is not a fit for this, and as I said before, no need to run to a pattern until it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

How about a [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

```
public class Event {
    public Event(IEnumerable<Task> tasks) {...}
}
```

with a builder api like so

```
new EventBuilder().AddTask(....).AddTask(....).AddTask(....).Build();
```

Comment: Thank you, I have looked at it. but the implementation of this pattern doesn't seem to quite suite the case